# Adwhirl android cant parse JSON

Tags: android, json, adwhirl

Hi im getting a error saying that adwhirl cannot parse json response
Im trying to load my ad into a AdwhirlLayout as stated in the documentation but it just says to me it cannot parse the json data.

```
02-13 16:00:20.260: D/AdWhirl SDK(13928): Prefs{null}: {"config": "", "timestamp": 1329144790626}
02-13 16:00:20.260: I/AdWhirl SDK(13928): Using stored config data
02-13 16:00:20.260: D/AdWhirl SDK(13928): Received jsonString: 
02-13 16:00:20.260: E/AdWhirl SDK(13928): Unable to parse response from JSON. This may or may not be fatal.
02-13 16:00:20.260: E/AdWhirl SDK(13928): org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
02-13 16:00:20.260: E/AdWhirl SDK(13928):   at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:446)
02-13 16:00:20.260: E/AdWhirl SDK(13928):   at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:93)
02-13 16:00:20.260: E/AdWhirl SDK(13928):   at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:154)
02-13 16:00:20.260: E/AdWhirl SDK(13928):   at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
02-13 16:00:20.260: E/AdWhirl SDK(13928):   at com.adwhirl.AdWhirlManager.parseConfigurationString(AdWhirlManager.java:290)
02-13 16:00:20.260: E/AdWhirl SDK(13928):   at com.adwhirl.AdWhirlManager.fetchConfig(AdWhirlManager.java:257)
02-13 16:00:20.260: E/AdWhirl SDK(13928):   at com.adwhirl.AdWhirlLayout$InitRunnable.run(AdWhirlLayout.java:376)
02-13 16:00:20.260: E/AdWhirl SDK(13928):   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:442)
02-13 16:00:20.260: E/AdWhirl SDK(13928):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
02-13 16:00:20.260: E/AdWhirl SDK(13928):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
02-13 16:00:20.260: E/AdWhirl SDK(13928):   at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:150)
02-13 16:00:20.260: E/AdWhirl SDK(13928):   at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:264)
02-13 16:00:20.260: E/AdWhirl SDK(13928):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1081)
02-13 16:00:20.260: E/AdWhirl SDK(13928):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:574)
02-13 16:00:20.260: E/AdWhirl SDK(13928):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1020)
```

my code:

```
AdWhirlLayout adWhirlLayout = (AdWhirlLayout) findViewById(R.id.adwhirlLayout);

    int diWidth = 320;
    int diHeight = 52; 
    int density = (int) getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

    adWhirlLayout.setAdWhirlInterface(this);
    adWhirlLayout.setMaxWidth((int) (diWidth * density));
    adWhirlLayout.setMaxHeight((int) (diHeight * density));
```

my key is specified in android manifest

Comment: can you put your code or your url from responce is come?

Comment: what is that `Prefs{null}:` ??

Comment: I get same error all of a sudden

Comment: Prefs{null} should be your adwhirl key btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the AdWhirl config server is down right now. You may want to try it again in an hour or so and hopefully it's back up by that point.